# How to calculate pearson correlation coefficient in given data set in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, math, statistics

I have spark DataFrame in which I have 2 **col** let's **col1** and **col2** with the double datatype. I want to calculate **Pearson correlation coefficient** in scala(in spark session).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your DataFrame is called "df". In order to compute the pearson correlation between 2 columns all you have to do is the following:

```
df.corr("col1", "col2", "pearson")
```

Comment: I tried but it throw the error like, value **corr** is not the member of org.apchae.spark.sql.Datafram

Comment: Make sure your `df` is a  spark DataFrame. I just tested it on 2.4.3 and it works.